# Distributed lock service implementation in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, locking

I have multiple E2E tests (written in Java) which share login details, each test during runtime will query the locker API for login details which is running on its own dedicated server.

Below is my implementation of my locker API in Go, it was working for me but wanted to make sure there are no bugs.

````golang
type service struct {
   lockstatus []string // stores test_id denoting which test took the lock
   data       []*LoginDetails // stores login details
   mu         []sync.Mutex // stores locks for "data" slice
}

func (s *service) AcquireLoginDetails(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
   foundLoginDetails := false
   for i := range s.mu {
      // for i, lock := range s.mu <- lock is copied here so will use s.mu[i] directly
      if s.mu[i].TryLock() {
         // skip to next lock if current lock is already taken
         if s.lockstatus[i] != "" {
            s.mu[i].Unlock()
            continue
         } else {
            // use this index to acquire lock for the requested test
            foundLoginDetails = true
            s.lockstatus[i] = req.GetTestID()
            resp.SetUserID(s.LoginDetails[i].UserID)
            resp.SetPassword(s.LoginDetails[i].Password)
         }
         s.mu[i].Unlock()
         if foundLoginDetails { break } // stop searching for further login details
      }
   }
   if !foundLoginDetails {
      return error_explaining_we_failed_to_acquire_lock
   }
   return nil
}

func (s *service) ReleaseLoginDetails(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
   foundLoginDetails := false
   for i, testID := range s.lockstatus {
      if testID == req.GetTestID() {
         s.mu[i].Lock()
         foundLoginDetails = true
         s.lockstatus[i] = ""
         s.mu[i].Unlock()
         break
      }
   }
   if !foundLoginDetails {
      return error_explaining_we_failed_to_release_lock
   }
   return nil
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see here is that your mutexes protect only the `data` slice, but they should also protect the `lockstatus` slice. Since they don't, you have a race condition where a `lockstatus` item can be written in `AcquireLoginDetails` (with the corresponding mutex acquired) and simultaneously read in `ReleaseLoginDetails` (on the `for` line), without the mutex acquired.

I think it would be slightly cleaner if, instead of three slices of equal length, your `service` object contained one slice of 3-tuples, each item containing its own `lockstatus`, `data`, and mutex:

```golang
type service struct {
  items []*serviceItem
}

type serviceItem struct {
  mu         sync.Mutex // protects data and lockstatus
  data       *LoginDetails
  lockstatus string
}
```

Making `items` a `[]*serviceItem` (instead of a `[]serviceItem`) lets you safely write:

```golang
for _, item := range s.items { ... }
```

without a lock-copying warning.

The documentation for `Mutex.TryLock` [says](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex.TryLock):

> Note that while correct uses of TryLock do exist, they are rare, and use of TryLock is often a sign of a deeper problem in a particular use of mutexes.

Indeed, you don't need `TryLock` here, as the code holds the lock briefly enough that it's no big deal to block waiting to acquire it.

Finally, as a matter of style, I would return early from these functions on success instead of having "found" vars; and I'd split out a helper function that lets you rely on `defer` for unlocking the mutex instead of having to write `Unlock` in two different code paths.

```golang
func (s *service) AcquireLoginDetails(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
  for _, item := range s.items {
    if tryAcquireItem(req, resp, item) {
      return nil
    }
  }
  return errCannotAcquire
}

func tryAcquireItem(req *Request, resp *Response, item *serviceItem) bool {
  item.mu.Lock()
  defer item.mu.Unlock()
  if item.lockstatus != "" {
    return false
  }
  item.lockstatus = req.GetTestID()
  resp.SetUserID(item.data.UserID)
  resp.SetPassword(item.data.Password)
  return true
}
```

(Similarly for `ReleaseLoginDetails`.)